# Heroku not serving static/public folder with Unicorn and Rails 2.3 app

Tags: heroku, assets, unicorn, cedar

I have been able to get Unicorn to start up properly with my Rails 2.3 app on Heroku's Cedar Stack, however, it is not serving the static assets correctly from the public folder. I have tried placing this line in our config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

But then our app fails to load properly. Without it, the app boots fine, just doesn't serve the static files. Is that line of code not compatible with Rails 2.3?

One note for people with the same sort of config, make sure to create a config.ru in your app root.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, but check out the [injected-plugins section of the Heroku Ruby support docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#injected-plugins).  It talks about a gem that may solve this issue by injecting this configuration after the app has been initialized.